# Monitor SQL server database for SP execution

Tags: .net, sql-server

We have a SQL server 2005 database on dev environment(multiple dev servers). Many of our systems(ASP.Net websites/web services) use it and almost every SP is being used by multiple systems. Sometimes the operation being carried out fails and many times the root cause turns out to be wrong data being passed to the SP. Tracing the exact cause proves to be a cumbersome task as often the SP calls are nested(one SP calls other SP which in turn calls another one). We have decided to create a tool which will show the SPs executed in the last few minutes on a given server along with the parameters passed to the SP. We don't know if it is remotely possible. Please suggest us any suitable approach to achieve this.

Comment: Are we talking about sql server profiler?

Comment: It does not show you the parameters passed to the SP.

Comment: Yes, it does show what parameters have been passed to the stored procedures. Even it shows the exact statement which was executed and you can just copy paste it in your sql server with transaction begin and rollback and analyse it.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch that data programmatically in C#.Net?

Comment: Server side SQL trace data can be retrieved programmatically with a query using the fn_trace_gettable table-valued function.  An Extended Event trace file can be read with fn_xe_file_target_read_file..